# Difference between die Station / der Bahnhof

Tags: vocabulary

What is the difference between the words die Station and der Bahnhof? Can they be used interchangably? When should one be used over the other?

Answer (score 4):

Most of the times these words cannot be used interchangeably, they are conceptually different.

*Bahnhof* means "station".

The word *Station* is a false friend, and it does not mean "station". *Station* is the a stop on a line. This can be on any line, regardless of the means of transportation, on a train, a bus, a ship, an airplane, you name it.

> Nächste Station: Altes Rathaus

> Wieviele Stationen hat die Linie 16?

A *Station* can happen to be a *Bahnhof*:

> Nächste Station: München Hauptbahnhof

But that does not imply that the words *Station* and *Bahnhof* are the same, just as english *stop* and *station* do not mean the same, although a stop can be a station.

Answer (score 4):

The two words are quite different and in general cannot be used interchangably.

*Bahnhof* is the German word for railway station. By extension, it is sometimes also used for other public transport facilities, such as *Busbahnhof* for a big bus station where many lines meet, or in a figurative sense such as *großer Bahnhof* for a big reception.

*Station* in German is originally a general word for a location where something or someone stops or remains for some time. Usages include the hospital ward, a refreshment point on a hike or run, or the waypoints of the catholic way of the cross, as well as the stopping points of public transport lines. It is not however in common use for an intersection point of railway lines. So "main station" must be translated as *Hauptbahnhof*. <s>*Hauptstation*</s> would be wrong.

Comment: Soll der letzte Satz eine doppelte Verneinung darstellen? Wie würdest Du ihn vorlesen?

Comment: Welcher letzte Satz? "Hauptstation would be wrong"? Da ist überhaupt keine Verneinung drin und ich würde ihn genau so vorlesen wie er dasteht, allenfalls mit einer leichten Stimmhebung auf dem ersten Wort zur Distanzierung.

Comment: Da ist eine Durchstreichung bei mir zu sehen - bei Dir nicht? Wie sonst, wenn nicht als Verneinung, würdest Du eine Durchstreichung interpretieren?

Comment: Die Durchstreichung kennzeichnet das Wort als falsch.

Comment: Aber im Satz "Hauptstation would be wrong" ist es ja nicht falsch, d.h. die Falschmarkierung ist da falsch.

Answer (score 2):

In formal terms, Bahnhof has to have at least one switch, else it is a Haltepunkt / Haltestelle.
Station is less common when talking about railroad, it may be of regional use or a generic term for any stop on a line, regardless of size. If the context is established, you may use Station occasionaly, just for variety.